# Why is .pause() for videos no longer working in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, video

I use pause() to stop a video. For some reason this does no longer work in chrome - the video stops briefly but then continues playing and I'm completely lost where my mistake might be.

A few months ago I developed a script that uses pause() to control video playback. Everything was working fine (and still is with Firefox) but for some reason it stopped working in chrome somewhere in the last two months. I've completly stripped it down to just a few lines of code and still my pause() function is no longer working in Chromium on Ubuntu 18.04 and the most recent Chrome on Windows 7.

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">

   $( document ).ready(function() {
       var vid = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
       $( "#videoplayer" ).click(function(e) {
           vid.pause();
       });
   });

</script>

</head>
<body>

<video width="1280" height="960" controls id="videoplayer">
 <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
```

(I know it is a somewhat ugly mixture of DOM and jquery because I use jquery for most of the rest of my script, but that shouldn't be a problem, should it?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you what changed, but adding `e.preventDefault` fixes it:

```
$( "#videoplayer" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <=====================
    vid.pause();
});
```

In general, if you've "handled" something, you want to prevent its default action.

My guess is that Chrome implemented a default action of toggling pause/play when you click the video. So your code pauses, then Chrome toggles it back to play.

That being the case, it may be worth allowing the default and not explicitly pausing, perhaps by introducing a timeout:

```
$( "#videoplayer" ).click(function(e) {
    if (!vid.paused) {               // Check that video is playing when clicked
        setTimeout(() => {           // V. brief timer to allow default action to occur
            if (!vid.paused) {       // Is it still playing?
                vid.pause();         // Pause it
            }
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: It means that chromium native player probably already handles click to toggle play/pause. Events are dispatched as expected.

Comment: @bigless - Yup, that was my theory too, which I just verified. Updated to suggest an option to the OP.

Comment: Ah, I didn't thought of that. Probably Chromium just changed the order in which the clicks are processed. Maybe before it first applied the default action toggle, pausing the video and then executed video.pause() and now it is the other way around. The would explain the behavior. Thanks for your help!